# Getting TomTom Traffic API XYZ data to display on map

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, api

I am using TomTom API to retrieve Traffic Data

`https://api.tomtom.com/traffic/map/4/tile/flow/relative0/12/1207/1539.png?tileSize=256&key=*****`

However, there is no coordinate reference system assigned, so I'm not sure where exactly this traffic data is for.

How can I figure this out so that I can convert to GeoJSON and correctly display it in QGIS for viewing?

Comment: replace 12/1207/1539 with {x}&y={y}&z={z}? QGIS will work the tiles out

Comment: @Mapperz replace the api call with your suggestion?